# Setting spark.driver.maxResultSize in EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to set the spark.driver.maxResultSize in my pyspark job.
I tried setting the conf setting inside my pyspark script like so:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")
```

But in my Spark environment it still shows the default 2G

[image]

I tried setting it in my AWS EMR spark-submit options with both `--spark.driver.maxResultSize 4g` and `--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize 4g` I get unrecongnized option as an error.

Am I missing the correct syntax?

Comment: Do you set the conf in the code before creating the SparkContext / SparkSession?

Comment: @OfekHod Yes I did

Answer (score 1):

I guess the syntax is `--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g`not `--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize 4g`
That seems to work and is showing up correctly in the Spark Environment.